# Excluding null properties in Criteria Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, null, criteria

How to remove null properties from Criteria Hibernate. For example

select ename, empno, empDate from employee where ename = 'check' and empno= '1234' and empdate = to_date("22-jul-2000", "DD-MON-YYYY")

In the above example, ename or empno or empdate any property might be null.

How to implement in Criteria

I am not  worried about the result set, I am worried about how the restrictions are added. I wan to avoid the following in the code:

```
if (((empno!= null) && (empno.trim().length()<=0)))
    {
        criteria.add(Restriction.eq("empno", empno))
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally you cannot remove single property from the result set, but you can set criteria that filters result out if certain attribute have null value:

```
criteria.add(Expression.isNotNull("ename"));
```

More details: [Hibernate Chapter 16. Criteria Queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) and [here](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/109-null-and-not-null-comparision-in-the-hibernat.html)